# How do I connect two computers with a LAN cable?

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection, lan

I have two machines - Windows XP and a laptop using Windows 7. I connected them with a WLAN cable.

On the Windows XP machine, I set the IP address to `192.168.0.10`.
On the Windows 7 laptop, I set the IP address to `192.168.0.20`.

The laptop can see the Windows XP machine, but Windows XP machine cannot see the Windows 7 machine. But this does NOT concern me. I want to move the files from my desktop (Windows XP) to Windows 7 (laptop). That's why I'm going through all this.

The problem is that when I try to connect from Windows 7 to Windows XP machine, I get this window:

[image]

I don't understand what username/password is needed. I use none on the Windows XP machine. I tried all usernames - no success.

Please explain in deep details how to solve my problem so I can connect to my Windows XP machine.

EDIT: Maybe this can help: the Windows XP machine is named 'I' and 'Проданов III' is the name of the laptop. Both computers share one workgroup - `WORKGROUP`.

Comment: Not necessarily related, but to make XP see Windows 7 open the Network and Sharing center and click on **Customize** to make the network a private network, you should then be able to see both ways.

Comment: That actually is quite related. Windows 7, by default, marks networks it doesn't know as public and sharing without passwords is disabled. If you mark a network as private, I think it should work.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find your username for I

   - Ctrl-Alt-Delete, it may show you the username as "you are logged in as I\USERNAME", or it will bring up the Task Manager.
   - If you see task manager, click on Users tab, that will give you the name that's logged in.
2. Set a password

   - Your account on I **must** have a password.
   - Start -> Control Panel -> User Accounts, then select your account and set a password.
   - While you're there, make sure this user is an administrator - it remove a lot of permission problems
3. After setting the password, reboot. Always reboot when in doubt.
4. Try connecting again from laptop

   - Username is I\USERNAME, whatever you found in step 1
   - Password is the password you just set

Answer (score 0):

Put in your account name used on the Windows XP machine and leave the password field blank.  Domain needs to be the Windows XP computer name.

Username: I\XPUser
Password:

Comment: Login failure: unknown username or bad password.I tried this before with more than one account. :(

Comment: still the same. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have had mixed results with Windows 7/Windows XP connectivity. Usually something gets weird in the 7 box and once I restart it, it works fine.

On the Windows 7 laptop can you try to navigate to \192.168.0.10\c$ ?

However, I do believe, you will need to set a password on the Windows XP machine for file sharing to work. You can use something simple temporarily like "p@ssw0rd"
Warning: Please set a strong(er) password on the 2 machines. But, hey, they are your machines do what you want :).

OTHERWISE, you can set the permissions on the share to Everyone Allow -> "All", which will literally allow EVERYONE to have access which I wouldn't do especially if you forget to turn it off....
Again, they are your computers do what you want, but you have been warned :).

Edit:

As a side note, do you have a share which you gave your user permissions to it?

Answer (score -1):

Its just a comment on above answers,

Its work when you press ctr and alt then delete , switch user and pass wors,!

When you just come to the specific device everything its working

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: "Its just a comment on above answers" - If you want to comment on one of the answers you should submit a comment not an answer.